# Is there a ip2location conversion for Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, geospatial

I am really interested in ip2location, because it is implemented in a way that I have all the data in my database, with no external lookup (YAY!).

However, ip2location is built on mysql + php.  I'm in the Microsoft world, with asp.net, SQL Server and WPF/Winforms.

I'm looking for a conversion of ip2location for .NET, which is basically just the SQL Server portion.

Any converted project out there?  If so, link or someone I can contact?

EDIT:
Someone should build something like this which is native to SQL Server.  The core requirement is to not rely on an external service, be fast, and give some level of accuracy to country (or closest server when no country is available).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the schema and bulk import fmt files are located here:  [link](http://www.ip2location.com/faqs-ip-country.aspx#10)

There is also a .csv file that appears to be dataset you are interested in posted here [link](http://ipcountryredirection.codeplex.com/)